# pivot on multiple column sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have below table and want to use pivot on multiple column using sum aggregate.

```
Category        Station1         Station2         Station3
-------------------------------------------------------------
Category1       5.26             6.25             7.28
Category2       4.22             5.00             6.00
Category3       5.00             4.00             8.00
Category1       4.00             7.00             9.00
Category2       2.00             5.00             8.00
```

And Want Output like

```
My_Station          Category1           Category2             Category3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Station1            Sum_of_Cat1         Sum_of_Cat2          Sum_of_Cat3
Station2            Sum_of_Cat1         Sum_of_Cat2          Sum_of_Cat3
Station3            Sum_of_Cat1         Sum_of_Cat2          Sum_of_Cat3
```

With Single Query. Not using any loop

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly a pivot.  You could unpivot and repivot.  I'm inclined to just write the SQL to do it:

```
select station as MyStation,
       sum(case when category = 'Category1' then value else 0 end) as Category1,
       sum(case when category = 'Category2' then value else 0 end) as Category2,
       sum(case when category = 'Category3' then value else 0 end) as Category3
from (select n.station, t.category,
             (case when station = 'Station1' then Station1
                   when station = 'Station2' then Station2
                   when station = 'Station3' then Station3
              end) as value
      from t cross join
           (select 'Station1' as station union all select 'Station2' union all select 'Station3') n
     ) t
group by station;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result by unpivoting the columns `station1`, `station2`, and `station3` first and then applying the PIVOT function.  The unpivot process converts multiple columns of data into multiple rows.

There are several methods that can be used to unpivot the data including the UNPIVOT function, a UNION ALL query or using CROSS APPLY.  You did not specify what version of SQL Server you are using but I implemented CROSS APPLY with UNION ALL so the code is:

```
select category, my_station, value
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  select 'station1', station1 union all
  select 'station2', station2 union all
  select 'station3', station3
) c (my_station, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/471b9/2). This gives a result of:

```
|  CATEGORY | MY_STATION | VALUE |
| Category1 |   station1 |  5.26 |
| Category1 |   station2 |  6.25 |
| Category1 |   station3 |  7.28 |
| Category2 |   station1 |  4.22 |
| Category2 |   station2 |     5 |
```

As you can see the multiple station columns are now in rows.  You can then apply the PIVOT function to convert the `category` values into columns:

```
select my_station, category1, category2, category3
from 
(
  select category, my_station, value
  from yourtable
  cross apply
  (
    select 'station1', station1 union all
    select 'station2', station2 union all
    select 'station3', station3
  ) c (my_station, value)
) d
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for category in (category1, category2, category3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/471b9/3). This gives a final result of:

```
| MY_STATION | CATEGORY1 | CATEGORY2 | CATEGORY3 |
|   station1 |      9.26 |      6.22 |         5 |
|   station2 |     13.25 |        10 |         4 |
|   station3 |     16.28 |        14 |         8 |
```